# Reading ldap group member from c#

Tags: c#, ldap, directoryentry

I have this code to connect to Active Directory and get all the groups that exist, it works and returns all the groups in results :

```
DirectoryEntry dirEnt = new DirectoryEntry();

using (DirectorySearcher srch = new DirectorySearcher(dirEnt, "(objectClass=Group)"))
            {
                srch.PageSize = 1000;
                SearchResultCollection results = srch.FindAll();
            }
```

I now want to return users of a specific group i.e. Administrators, how would I go about this?

I had tried changing (objectClass=Group) to (objectClass=Group)(cn=*admin*) but then it returns no results.

All the best

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a reference about how to in Active Directory:

[Howto: (Almost) Everything In Active Directory via C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/everythingInAD.aspx)